# Poor migration options

Tags: discussion, migration

Closing for migration is a bit tough.  Right now, if you don't want to send the post to SU or meta, you have to move back up the close tree.

My suggestion is to add a manual "other" option to the off topic -> migration option.

Of course, the default is where it seems to be going right now, which is a generic "unclear what you're asking" path, which is simply the easiest, requiring nothing but a selection and no typing, but this doesn't feel right.

I'm not quite sure how the act of migrating actually interfaces with the close choice, but I think this is one of those small things that make review chores a bit more tedious for those who choose to do them.  I find myself clicking skip more often, lately.

Comment: You can close for "off topics" and one of the sub-choices is "this question belongs on a different stack exchange site." But then the only choices for places to migrate are superuser or Meta.EE. (While it seems to me the most common places we need to migrate are Arduino and DIY)

Comment: We're not obligated to fix it for someone that can't be bothered to post in the right place.  Just close it and move on.  If there isn't a close reason that seems to fit, pick the nearest handy one.  Again, it's not worth wasting our time fixing someone else's stupidity.  If they aren't told exactly why their question was closed, oh well.  They could try reading the rules and learning the site better before blurting out a question next time.  Kicking people like that in the butt as they're being thrown out is a Good Thing.

Comment: @ThePhoton -- that's the point -- the "different exchange" option is gone.  It was there a few days ago, but I can't see it.

Comment: @Scott  re: Your second paragraph.  I can still see the *off-topic → belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network* option on a fresh post.  May be I can see it only because I have moderator access.  The questions older than 60 days can not be migrated [as an aside, I question that policy myself].  Possibly, when you didn't find the migration option, you were looking at an old question.

Comment: @NickAlexeev, When I look at one, the only migration options are Superuser and Meta. There's no "fill-in-the-blank" choice. So this option is useless if Superuser or Meta isn't the migration target.

Comment: @NickAlexeev -- right you are!!  I'll edit later and catch this up to reality.  The original intent was to say how the current migrate options miss the mark, and an "other" manual field would be cool.  Then I pulled up an old example, and came to a wrong conclusion!

Comment: @ThePhoton -- I agree, but somewhat disagree with the "useless" part.  I think its less than useless, as by the time you come to that conclusion you've moved down a tree to a dead end, and have to go back up the tree.  Just poor user interfacing, which I'd think SE would rather avoid.

Comment: @ScottSeidman, totally agree. I believe the UX guys call this a "misaffordance".

Comment: @OlinLathrop If none of the close reasons apply, you are probably closing a valid question.

Comment: @mark: Sometimes questions are just crap.  They may not fit a official close reason, but they still need to be closed.  For example, lots of lower case "i", text speak, painful formatting, no periods, no capitalization of first letters, etc.  No, they shouldn't be edited to let the asker slide by and get away with gross disrespect.  Sometimes the catch-all *unclear* applies, but not always.

Comment: @The Photon: There's actually more to it than misaffordance. Misaffordance is the part you go into the migration menu only to see that there's nothing useful there. The worst part (for me) is where you "lose your work" by having to go back all the way to beginning of the close-voting process. I forgot what's the name for that in the usability jargon (if I ever knew it).

Comment: @RespawnedFluff  Maybe we should ask on the User Experience stack

Comment: @Scott Seidman: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/85496/is-there-a-name-in-ux-jargon-for-the-lose-your-work-anti-pattern