# Why can't one decide what SE does the question belongs to when flagging?

Tags: bug

[image: Gives me only one option]Gives me only one option when I tried to flag the question as it belongs to probably stack overflow. I wanted to flag that question so that it can be migrated to stackoverflow.SE Why am I not getting the option to select the site that I think it belongs to ?

Comment: Titles are for giving a indication and reminder what the question is about, not for content.  The question body must be able to stand on its own without relying on the title or tags.

Comment: i hope it makes sense now!

Comment: Related: https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2800/more-migration-options and https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5110/poor-migration-options

Comment: Also, for information, there have been some posts on the main meta about this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79960/when-voting-to-migrate-an-off-topic-question-why-is-the-list-of-sites-limited and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96205/more-options-when-flagging-for-migration.

Comment: So should I just mark it to belong to superuser and move ahead and moderator will figure out where to send?

Comment: No, you should rather flag it for moderator attention and add an explanation on the text box. Not close it for migration at all.

Comment: Alright, seems fair